# Alternative to a Reflection-Based Event System?

Tags: java, events, reflection

Currently I'm creating a mod for a game. I am using a reflection-based event system at the moment. I want to get rid of the system because frankly.. reflection is bad (performance-wise). What this reflection-based event system did however would do something like this:

```
 class Mod extends ModBase implements EventListener{

 @EventHandler
 void runCode(Event event){ // When a Event object is created...
 }

 }
```

I still want to use an event system, however, I just don't want it to use reflection. Does anyone have an suggestions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern

Comment: Reflection is only "bad" if you check the listeners everytime when an event is fired, but not if you check the listeners only once on application's startup and remember them.